# High side power switch IC drops 0.5V when loaded

Tags: high-side

I setup a circuit shown in AP2411 data sheet on a solder-less test board and connected the output to 30 ohm resistor to ground to simulate about 100mA of current. Input voltage is 3.3V from a lab power supply and looks clean on a scope. Output voltage when the resistor is open is 3.3V. However, when the resistor is connected to ground, the output voltage is about 2.8V. Is that normal to lose almost 0.5V when using power switch IC?

[image]

[image]

Comment: First off, with an output of 3.3v the current should be 110ma using a 30 ohm load. The AP2411 is listed as having a 70m ohm on resistance, so the voltage drop at 110ma should only be 0.0077v, (or 0.04 v at 200ma).   Do you have the enable pin pulled high (not open).  Is the input voltage dropping?  Are you sure you have a 30 ohm resistor not a 3 ohm?  Is the chip getting warm? May be recheck all connections.

Comment: Based on a quick glance at the datasheet, I'd expect a much lower voltage drop. Can you share a photo of your setup? Have you checked for poor connections? Have you measured Vin when the switch is loaded? (In fact, you might want to measure the voltage drop with a multimeter right across Vin and Vout)

Comment: If using the 8-pin version are you connecting the 2 input pints together, and the two output pins together, as recommended?

Comment: Thanks for reviewing. so, the resistor is 30.6 ohm, 10W.  Yes, i have two outputs together and inputs. To @marcelm - Thanks for reviewing. I rechecked the connections - they seem ok, aside from the solder-less board being not the best connection method, but i thought it should be ok. I added the picture.

Comment: Just for kicks I've built the circuit exactly as you had it, lousy wiring and all. The voltage drop measured between pins 2+3 and 6+7 is not what you claim. It's exactly what it should be per the datasheet. It was <10mV when I measured it. This was a measurement error on your part. The voltage across the resistor of course is low as you saw it, because all the drops are elsewhere, not on the switch. The switch wasn't to blame :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP24x1.pdf) gives the on resistance when driven from 3.3 V as typically 90 mΩ, max 108 mΩ at 25 C, which for your 100 mA of current should give a drop in the order of 10 mV.

Check your lab power supply isn't current limiting at 100 mA, use it to drive the resistor directly while measuring voltages.

If the supply is OK, then either the part is broken, you're not driving enable correctly, or you're losing voltage somewhere else. Using your meter, measure the drop **directly** across the part, and the drop on any wires, traces and soldered or socketed joints between the supply, the part, and the load, as well as the load voltage and the supply voltage.

Question - are you plugging your load resistor into a breadboard? Those boards are notorious for having poor contact resistance. If the IC is plugged in to the board as well, you have at least four (maybe 6 or 8!) lousy joints in series between your power supply and your load resistor.

Comment: supply limit is set to 400mA. I moved around the resistor connections around. I guess, my main question is - is that IC OK to use to switch on/off voltage 3.3V for a circuit that draws around 100-200mA? I will try to solder all the components to see if it makes a difference. Thanks

Comment: The IC is specfied for 2 A, so it will manage 200 mA without breaking a sweat, without the slightest murmur of complaint, and without needing to do any sums about heating and heatsinking.

Comment: You all were correct about cabling. I am embarrassed. I soldered all the circuit components. Got about .1V better, but the drop was still around 0.4V. My home-made power supply cable had 2.5 ohm for positive line and 1.3ohm for negative. At about 110mA it came up to about 0.28V in "+" leg and 0.14 in "-" leg. About .42V total. That was my issue. The cable was attached to banana clip via a screw, not soldered. So much for convenience of mechanical connection.
Thanks all!!